# Why winform user control resize event was trigger event no any resize command

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, resize, windows-forms-designer

To repeat my problem:

1. Add a new user control.
2. Add follow method and register to Resize event in contructor.

   ```
   Resize += new EventHandler(AutoResize);

   private void UserControl2_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       MessageBox.Show($"{Width}:{Height}");
   }
   ```
3. Rebuild and add this user control to a winform. And I found this method was call every winform was loaded.
4. If I register this method to Resize in Onload event, then this method never called except when I really resize it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following facts:

- The `Rezize` event of the `UserControl` will happen when `Size` changes.
- The `Load` event of the `UserControl` will happen when the handle of the control created.
- When you drop the control on form, the following code will be generated for the control:

  ```
  // 
  // userControl11
  // 
  this.userControl11.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
  this.userControl11.Name = "userControl11";
  this.userControl11.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 150);
  this.userControl11.TabIndex = 0;
  ```
- At this line `this.userControl11.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 150);`
  The `Load` event has not been raised, but the constructor has been executed.

Considering the facts, when you subscribe for the `Resize` event in constructor, then `this.userControl11.Size = ...` will raise the `Resize` event and the event will be handled by your event handler.

But when you subscribe for `Resize` in `Load` event of the control, that initial resize will not be handled by your event handler, because you still haven't subscribed for the `Resize` event, because the control still has not been created.